# count number of xml element from linux shell

Tags: python, xml, linux, perl

My xml looks something like this :

```
<elements>
<elem>
....bunch of other elements
</elem>
</elements>
```

Is there a way to count the number of occurances of `elem` tag in some xml file trough linux shell? like with perl/python or anything that might work as one liner?

I might try something like `grep -c "elem" myfile.xml` and the number I get divide it by `2` and get the number, is there something similar but one liner?

**EDIT :**

I'm looking for alternative grep solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@OP, all the `grep` solutions has a fundamental "flaw" in that it will miss counts if more than 1 `<elem>` tags is one a line. Use `awk` to count programmatically

```
awk 'BEGIN{
    totalelem=0
    totalendelem=0
}
/<elem>/{
    m = split($0,a,"<elem>") # or m = gsub(/<elem>/,"")
    totalelem+=m-1
}
/<\/elem>/{
    m = split($0,b,"</elem>") # or m = gsub("</elem>","")
    totalendelem+=m-1
}
END{
    print "Total elem tags: " totalelem
    print "Total end elem tags: " totalendelem
    # if you want to make sure each elem tag is enclosed  by corresponding end elem tag
    if ( totalelem == totalendelem ){
        print "Equal start and end tags"
    }
}
' file
```

this solution assumes you know how your elem tags will be like. No `<elem />` or those with extra attributes..

Comment: thank you for your response, but I need to pass file content to this with pipe and then type awk/grep or whatever command, is that possible with this? how do you save awk script as .awk? currently I get `awk:                                          ^ syntax error`

Comment: save it as a shell script. Then call the shell script from the command line. eg `./myscript.sh`. Make sure to make it executable.

Answer (score 15):

The `xml_grep` tool does what you want - try the following:

```
xml_grep --count //elem example.xml
```

That utility is in the `xml-twig-tools` package on Debian / Ubuntu, and the [documentation is here](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/tools/xml_grep/xml_grep).

Comment: @Mark Longair this seems ok, but I can't find that command on my linux, how can I install it?

Comment: @London: What distribution are you using?

Comment: I don't have access to a Red Hat system, but you could try: `yum install perl-XML-Twig`

Comment: It also installs with `cpan XML::Twig`

Comment: you can even write xml_grep --count elem example.xml (no need for the //)

Comment: Worked like a charm. I only had to get the package installed ! Thanks Mark

Answer (score 15):

You can also use `xmllint`:

```
xmllint --xpath "count(//elem)" myfile.xml
```

Comment: Currently this is the best answer so far in this thread. Using a proper xml tool is the way to go, not some hacky grep solution.

Comment: What if the element has a namespace prefix?

Answer (score 3):

**DO NOT USE REGULAR EXPRESSIONS TO PARSE OR SCAN XML FILES**

The mandatory disclaimer being fired, here's my solution:

```
xmllint --nocdata --format myfile.xml | grep -c '</elem>'
```

`xmllint` is part of [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/) which is fairly common on many linux distros. This solution passes the following regex/XML traps:

- spurious spaces (--format)
- several closing tags on single line (--format)
- CDATA sections (--nocdata)

However, you will be caught by nasty namespace declaration and defaults.

Comment: you're stating don't use regexes and yet you give a solution using the regex?

Comment: @London That's the irony... The warning must be issued at every occasion. Though you seemed to look for a solution from the shell. I gave you one that has, imho, a good compromise between correctness and quickness.

Answer (score 1):

London,

Try `fgrep -c '</elem>' $filename`

`fgrep` is a standard unix utility, not at all sure about linux though. The `-c` switch means *count*.

Cheers. Keith.

PS: It's allmost allways easier to count CLOSING tags, coz they don't have attributes ;-)

Comment: counting closing tags may yield wrong results, due to the short form <elem /> for a closed tag. Also, the usual 'you cannot parse xml via regex'-arguments apply, eg: <<CDATA[[ <elem> ]]>>

Comment: Yeah... hadn't though of `<elem />`'s ... Bugger!

Comment: Moreover grep count matching lines and not matches. So if there are several `<elem/>` in a single line, they will increase the counter by one only.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` alone won't help in all cases, but this is an easy case for [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/). You can match `elem` with `XMLStarlet` and then count the new lines with `wc -l`. The new lines minus 1 is the number of elements.

Example YOURFILE.xml:

```
<elements>
<elem>....bunch of other elements</elem><elem>....bunch of other elements</elem>
<elem>
....bunch of other elements
....bunch of other elements
</elem>
</elements>
```

Use `XMLStarlet` and `wc-l`:

```
echo $(($(xmlstarlet sel -t -m //elem -n YOURFILE.xml | wc -l)-1))
```

Output: `3`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a refinement to @bluenote10's [xmllint answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35576314/1209004) that also works for arbitrary namespace prefixes :

```
xmllint --xpath "count(//*[local-name()='elem'])" myfile.xml
```

(Already tried to add this as a response to @Ryan_Pelletier's question below the original answer, but kept running into formatting issues so created a separate answer instead).